Do not run pipeline after changing kustomization file
I am using ArgoCD Image Updater, with the latest update strategy. To modify the image tags, I am using the Kustomize method and my repository is GitLab (local). After modifying the kustomize file, it pushes the changes. Depending on the when: parameter in gitlab-ci, the pipeline will not be executed automatically. My problem is that my pipeline is always executed, as it is the ideal way for my projects to work. And that is when I came across a looping problem, because imagine the following case:

The developer makes a change in the code and sends it to the repository;
The pipeline is executed automatically, thus generating the container image;
The ArgoCD image updater recognizes that there is a more recent image in the repository, modifies the tag in the kustomize file and sends the modification to GitLab.

With this, you can already imagine how the looping is caused.
I found an 'easy' solution to my problem, which would be to run a git push -o ci.skip instead of git push. Does anyone know if there is a file in the argocd image updater pod where I can change this or something like that?
